# unable to plot a pie chart

Tags: python, pandas, pie-chart, epoch

I have a dataset in epoch nano seconds

```
       M            d          time      
0  1081083  28000000000  1.530683e+18  
1  1081083  16000000000  1.530683e+18  
2  1081085  33000000000  1.530683e+18  
3  1081083  28000000000  1.530683e+18  
4  1081085  27000000000  1.530683e+18
```

which on conversion looks like this:

```
      M         d           time
0  1081083  07:16:40 2018-07-04 05:42:20  
1  1081083  09:56:40 2018-07-04 05:43:03  
2  1081085  16:10:00 2018-07-04 05:43:12  
3  1081083  07:16:40 2018-07-04 05:43:51  
4  1081085  05:30:00 2018-07-04 05:44:01
```

For conversion of epoch to normal the codes are:

```
import pandas as pd
import time
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


df1 = pd.read_csv('testsy_1.csv')

df1['time']=pd.to_datetime(df1['time'], unit='ns')

df1['d']=df1['d'].apply(lambda x: time.strftime("%H:%M:%S",time.localtime(x)))
```

But when trying get a pie-chart for df1['M'],df1['d'] :

```
plt.figure(figsize=(16,8))
ax1 = plt.subplot(121, aspect='equal')
df1.plot(kind='pie', y = 'd', ax=ax1, autopct='%1.1f%%', 
startangle=90, shadow=False, labels=df1['M'], legend = False, fontsize=14)
```

I get a error as :

`TypeError: Empty 'DataFrame': no numeric data to plot`

How dataframe is empty as converted data is already there ? How to plot here the pie chart ?

As suggested by @jezrael I omitted `df1['d']=df1['d'].apply(lambda x: time.strftime("%H:%M:%S",time.localtime(x)))` and executed the script without any change fetch me the results for the df.head() of the dataset.

But when applying the above this for a full dataset of about 23000 rows, I get a horrible plot...What is the problem?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is problem `d` values are not numeric.

So you can convert `d` column to timedeltas and then to seconds:

```
df1['d'] = pd.to_timedelta(df1['d']).dt.total_seconds()
print (df1)
         M        d                time
0  1081083  26200.0 2018-07-04 05:42:20
1  1081083  35800.0 2018-07-04 05:43:03
2  1081085  58200.0 2018-07-04 05:43:12
3  1081083  26200.0 2018-07-04 05:43:51
4  1081085  19800.0 2018-07-04 05:44:01
```

[image: pic]

Or if possible omit:

```
df1['d']=df1['d'].apply(lambda x: time.strftime("%H:%M:%S",time.localtime(x)))
```

[image: graph]

Comment: omitting `df1['d']=df1['d'].apply(lambda x: time.strftime("%H:%M:%S",time.localtime(x)))` works , applying same strategy for 23000 rows doesn't give a pleasant pie-chart. Kindly take a look in main problem section , I have updated the the screenshot of pie-chart too for 23000 rows. @jezrael Where change is needed ?

Comment: @suryarahul - In my opinion problem is logic - you plot for each row of DataFrame one  piece of pie graph. So There is possible aggregate data like `df = df.groupby('M', as_index=False)['d'].sum()` and then plot.

Comment: `df = df.groupby('M', as_index=False)['d'].sum()` is meant for each row or the sum of the rows ? @jezrael

Comment: @suryarahul - Yes, idea is create less rows, because 23k rows plot to pie is possible, but result is awfull

Comment: means `df = df.groupby('M', as_index=False)['d'].sum()` will give aggregate  result of rows. one question @jezrael how anyone particular row can be plotted as a pie chart ?

Comment: You can select DataFrame, e.g. by positions - `df1.iloc[[0]` - it plot only one row (first) in pie. `ax1 = plt.subplot(121, aspect='equal')
df1.iloc[[0]].plot(kind='pie', y = 'd', ax=ax1, autopct='%1.1f%%', 
startangle=90, shadow=False, labels=df1['M'], legend = False, fontsize=14)`. If want first `10` rows: `plt.figure(figsize=(16,8))
ax1 = plt.subplot(121, aspect='equal')
df1.iloc[:10].plot(kind='pie', y = 'd', ax=ax1, autopct='%1.1f%%', 
startangle=90, shadow=False, labels=df1['M'], legend = False, fontsize=14)`